# How to check and extract the url containing the random number with the status code

Tags: python, random

```
import string
import random
import requests

_LENGTH = 5 
string_pool = string.digits
result = ""
for i in range(_LENGTH):
    result += random.choice(string_pool) 

url = "http://bbs.blabla.com/" + result
response = requests.get(url)

if response.status_code = 200:
    print(url)
```

Based on the following function, How do I code to identify and extract accessible URLs with status codes?
I want to know both how to extract all URLs and how to extract first URL. I would really appreciate it if you let me know the code including multiprocessing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a complete answer, but I would start by using [`random.choices()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choices) instead of `random.choice()` to generate the random identifier:

```
import string
import random

LENGTH = 5
random_id = ''.join(
    random.choices(string.digits, k=LENGTH))
```

Or, if the random identifiers will always be numbers, then you could use [`random.randint()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.randint) directly:

```
import random

LENGTH = 5
MIN_NUM = 10 ** (LENGTH - 1)
MAX_NUM = 10 ** LENGTH - 1
print('MIN_NUM', MIN_NUM)
print('MAX_NUM', MAX_NUM)

random_id = random.randint(MIN_NUM, MAX_NUM)
```

Both of these options are faster/cleaner than the for-loop that you showed.

---

Other than that I don't know what exactly you are asking, it seems like your code is already doing what it should (except for a small typo; change `=` to `==` in the `if` line).

You could just wrap the whole thing in a loop and repeat it as many times as necessary:

```
import random
import requests

BASE_URL = 'http://bbs.blabla.com/'
LENGTH = 5
MIN_NUM = 10 ** (LENGTH - 1)
MAX_NUM = 10 ** LENGTH - 1
print('MIN_NUM', MIN_NUM)
print('MAX_NUM', MAX_NUM)

for _ in range(1000):
    random_id = random.randint(MIN_NUM, MAX_NUM)
    url = BASE_URL + str(random_id)
    # print('url', url)

    resp = requests.get(url)
    if resp.status_code == 200:
        print(url, 'is OK')
```